# Let BillboardCollection and LabelCollection inherit position from entity its in

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to get around the problem where TextureAtlas would overflow if I make a dynamic label with a svg where I have text elements constantly changing.

My idea was to use and entity as a label, with a BillboardCollection for the background and a LabelCollection for the text. But I'm realising that the Collections are not really part of the entity I put them in which I guess makes sense somehow. 
Is there a way to make the billboardCollection and LabelCollection that is part of an entity to inherit the position of that entity if no separate position is specified? 
If this doesn't work, do I need to place each graphical element and text into separate entities?

What is the best praxis for a dynamic label with a background of my choice that is expected to be updated very very very very much, with a lot of similar labels without killing Cesium because of an overflow in the TextureAtlas?

Comment: Is all of the changing label text known in advance, or is the new text being fed into the browser in realtime?

Comment: usually in advance, but realtime occurs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cesium's Entities have labels and billboards, but they typically share a single LabelCollection and BillboardCollection among the active entities.  The text of the labels can change frequently, but the TextureAtlas is careful to re-use glyphs it has already seen from the same font.  When used correctly, this should prevent it from overflowing.

Allowing each entity to manage its own collection defeats this optimization, and you can get an overflow much more quickly.  The whole collection is intended to render with a single draw call, so if each entity manages a collection, then you get separate draw calls per-entity, which gets expensive fast.  In the normal flow, all entities with billboards share a single BillboardCollection, and a single draw call gets all the billboards on the screen, and then a second draw call gets all the labels from all the entities on the screen.

Here's a sample of a time-varying label on an entity.  This should produce an entity with a label that changes text very rapidly when the animation is playing.

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false,
    // These next 5 lines are just to avoid the Bing Key error message.
    imageryProvider : Cesium.createTileMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : Cesium.buildModuleUrl('Assets/Textures/NaturalEarthII')
    }),
    baseLayerPicker : false,
    geocoder : false,
    // This next line fixes another Stack Snippet error, you may omit
    // this setting from production code as well.
    infoBox : false
});

var startTime = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2016-08-01T00:00:00Z');
var intervalStart = startTime;

var labelText = new Cesium.TimeIntervalCollectionProperty();

for (var x = 0; x < 86400; ++x) {
    var intervalStop = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(startTime, x, new Cesium.JulianDate());
    labelText.intervals.addInterval(new Cesium.TimeInterval({
        start: intervalStart,
        stop: intervalStop,
        data: 'Time ' + x
    }));
    intervalStart = intervalStop;
}

var clock = viewer.clock;
clock.startTime = startTime;
clock.stopTime = intervalStart;
clock.currentTime = startTime;
clock.clockRange = Cesium.ClockRange.CLAMPED;
clock.multiplier = 30;
viewer.timeline.zoomTo(clock.startTime, clock.stopTime);

viewer.entities.add({
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
    label : {
        text : labelText
    }
});
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.20/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.20/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```